# How to communicate between Docker containers

Tags: node.js, powershell, docker, windows-container

I am new to Docker and containerization methods in general so I may be just thinking about this wrong, but I am trying to setup a **PowerShell as a Service** type of application where a client can communicate to a powershell shell in 2 ways:

1. A light-weight HTTP API
2. An HTTP WebSocket

According to what I have read, we want each service to be in its own container which means I think I need 2 different containers:

1. One container would host PowerShell on Windows using the docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/powershell` and is pre-built with the AzureAD module for PowerShell.
2. The other container would host my API endpoint that is publicly available on some address like `http:localhost:8080`.

I want to be able to run something like:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/powershell/command
{
    "command": "Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId <guid>"
}
```

Then I would *somehow* pipe that "command" through to the PowerShell instance running in the other container.  Where I get confused is how can this be done? As-is, the PowerShell hosted windows container doesn't expose any ports or any way to communicate with it. Its basically a black box that you can only interact with via something like `docker run -it <image>` right?  This command allows me to remote (is that the right term for it?) into the container and run commands in PowerShell.

The only way I can think of doing this is to NOT use 2 containers and instead use a dotnet-mvc or node-windows image as my base, create a second image that includes the installation of powershell, and then finally use that second image to host the entirety of my application. Then, inside the .NET MVC or NodeJS application I would be responsible for forking a node psuedo-terminal using something like `node-pty`. And since my image already includes the AzureAD module from the dockerfile I should be able to just pipe commands through to the psuedo-terminal via stdin/stdout.

I see this application as having 2 distinct services, so it feels "hacky" to use a single container, but if this is the only solution I guess thats what I have to do.

Any guidance or tips on how I could accomplish this are welcome! 
Thank you

Comment: Yes, powershell inside container will not expose any port for you to invoke it remotely. You might be able to invoke commands remotely through WinRM but you will for sure face issues with authentication at minimum. I'm not sure why you want separate container for this sort of setup. Just install powershell in the same container since it's not really designed to be used as `service` in a first place

Comment: @GregorySuvalian so is this a good use case for using docker's multi-stage builds? I read a little about them but I'm not entirely sure I understand their usage.  Could I have a single dockerfile that has a `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell` and a `FROM stefanscherer/node-windows` in order to get both on a single container? Or do I have to start with one of those base images and deal with installing the other one manually?

Comment: powershell modifies a bunch of things in registry and other places, multi-stage build will not be able to export those, so you have to install powershell through normal `RUN` statement

Comment: Ah ok thank you for the tip! I will give it a show